# How to mock a local variable b (which uses private method) without using power mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

```
public class A {
    public void methodOne(int argument) {
        //some operations
        B b = methodTwo(int argument);

        // some operations based on b
        // switch cases based on returned values of b

    }

    private void methodTwo(int argument)
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime();
    //use dateTime to perform some operations
}
```

Comment: Dont put more information in comments. Always update your question instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must mock class `B`, then you can do it as follows (without using PowerMock, but instead the JMockit library):

```
public class ExampleTest {
    @Tested A a;

    @Test
    public void exampleTest(@Mocked B anyB) {
        // Record calls to methods on B, if/as needed by code under test:
        new Expectations() {{ anyB.doSomething(); result = "mock data"; }};

        // Exercise the code under test:
        a.methodOne(123);

        // Verify a call to some other method on B, if applicable:
        new Verifications() {{ anyB.someOtherMethod(anyString, anyInt); }};
    }
}
```

Note this test does not care how `A` obtains `B`. It is independent of implementation details such as `private methodTwo`, as a good test should always be.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you don't!

Meaning: your methodOne() is returning a certain value. So, if possible, you should prefer to **not** test internals.

Thus, you should write test cases that invoke methodOne() with various parameters; and then assert that the value returned by that method matches your exceptions.

If you really need to control that "B" object in order to do reasonable testing, the correct way to get there is to use **dependency injection** and provide a B object to your class under test somehow. Because then you can create a mocked B and hand that to your class under test.

In other words: learn how to write testable code; for example by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79). Seriously; each minute of that material is worth your time.

Comment: Thank you.. I will go through videos

Comment: There is no such thing as "*the* correct way" to control an object "B" used from class "A". Dependency injection is an option among others, and each option comes with its own trade-offs.